# Active Admin - some custom js won't load in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline, activeadmin

I just deployed an application in production environment :

- debian
- nginx + unicorn
- ruby 1.9.3 + rails 3.1.0

I didn't have any any problem in development mode :

- mac osx 10.7.5
- webrick
- ruby 1.9.3 + rails 3.1.0

I added some custom **.js** in my active admin application like this :

```
config.register_javascript 'tiny_mce/jquery.tinymce.js'
config.register_javascript 'jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.min.js'
config.register_javascript 'active_admin_custom.js'
```

active_admin_custom.js was correctly load in production but not the others, any idea to fix it ?

This is my environments/production.rb :

```
# Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this)
config.serve_static_assets = false

# Compress JavaScripts and CSS
config.assets.compress = true

# Don't fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed
config.assets.compile = true

# Generate digests for assets URLs
config.assets.digest = true
```

Comment: Can you post the output of 
ls -la app/assets/javascripts and 
ls -la vendor/assets/javascripts
please?

Comment: The file structure have change so this question is outdated. I remember it was a cache problem... But thanks for your help ^^

Answer (score 2):

When I see this problem it usually relates to assets not being compiled because it's not included via the asset manifest files - using `register_javascript` in ActiveAdmin doesn't seem to get this right, so I stick with putting `require` commands into active_admin.js instead:

**active_admin.js**:

```
//= require active_admin/base
//= require cocoon
//= require jquery-ui
//= require tinymce-jquery
```

That way the javascript is included correctly in development, but also correctly compiled for production.